# Getting Fewest Instructions for `rsqrtss` Wrapper

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, icc

I figured it was about time to use a fast reciprocal square root.  So, I tried writing a function (which would be marked `inline` in production):

```
float sqrt_recip(float x) {
  return _mm_cvtss_f32( _mm_rsqrt_ss( _mm_set_ps1(x) ) ); //same as _mm_set1_ps
}
```

**TL;DR: My question is "how can I get GCC and ICC to output minimal assembly (two instructions) for the above function, preferably without resorting to raw assembly (sticking with intrinsics)?"**

As written, on ICC 13.0.1, GCC 5.2.0, and Clang 3.7 the output is:

```
shufps  xmm0, xmm0, 0
rsqrtss xmm0, xmm0
ret
```

This makes sense, since I used `_mm_set_ps1` to scatter `x` into all components of the register.  But, I don't really need to do that.  I'd prefer only doing the last two lines.  Sure, `shufps` is only one cycle.  But `rsqrtss` is only three to five.  It's 20% to 33% overhead that's completely worthless.

---

**Some things I tried:**

- I tried just not setting it:
  `union { __m128 v; float f[4]; } u;`
  `u.f[0] = x;`
  `return _mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_rsqrt_ss(u.v));`
  This actually works for Clang, but the output for ICC and GCC in particular is appalling.
- Instead of scattering, you can fill with zeroes (that is, use `_mm_set_ss`).  Again, neither GCC nor ICC's output is optimal.  In GCC's case, GCC hilariously adds this:
  `movss  DWORD PTR [rsp-12], xmm0`
  `movss  xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsp-12]`

---

Comment: The "hilarious" code is there to clear the top 3 floats in xmm0 as required by the intrinsic. Presumably gcc thinks that's more efficient than the `pxor`.

Comment: @Jester [So it does](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_205.html). Still, that's beside the point since we only care about the 0th float and so the clear, like the `shufps`, should be elided.

Comment: Yup, intrinsics are dumb and only clang knows how to optimize away zero-extension from `_mm_set_ss` when you're only using the scalar result (and maybe the the broadcast from `_mm_set1_ps`).  The general case of this question is [How to merge a scalar into a vector without the compiler wasting an instruction zeroing upper elements? Design limitation in Intel's intrinsics?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39318496), which still doesn't have any answer other than inline asm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is three-and-a-half years later and, while compilers have advanced and the situation has gotten better, they still do not output optimal code.

However, without dropping to raw assembly, we can still do better than intrinsics by using inline assembly.  We have to be a bit careful; there is a significant penalty for switching between non-VEX-encoded and VEX-encoded instructions, so we need two codepaths.

This produces optimal results on GCC (9.0.1), Clang (9.0.0), and ICC (19.0.1.144).  It only produces optimal results on MSVC (19.16) when inlined and not VEX-encoded (and this probably as-good as we can do since MSVC doesn't support inline assembly on x86-64):

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>


inline float rsqrt_fast(float x) {
    #ifndef _MSC_VER //Optimal
        float result;
        asm( //Note AT&T order
            #ifdef __AVX__
            "vrsqrtss %1, %1, %0"
            #else
            "rsqrtss %1, %0"
            #endif
            : "=x"(result)
            : "x"(x)
        );
        return result;
    #else //TODO: not optimal when in AVX mode or when not inlined
        return _mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_rsqrt_ss(_mm_set_ps1(x)));
    #endif
}
```